# Converting a .caffemodel to keras h5

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, caffe

I want to fine tune a gender detector trained in caffe using my own data set. This model was trained by using around half a million face images. They fine tuned VGG16 pre-trained on ImageNet. I want to use this model as my base model.I downloaded gender.caffemodel file from this link:

[IMDB-Wiki](https://data.vision.ee.ethz.ch/cvl/rrothe/imdb-wiki/)

I've used the tool provided in link below to convert this model to an h5 file to use in Keras:

[https://github.com/pierluigiferrari/caffe_weight_converter](http://Caffe-to-Keras%20Weight%20Converter)

This tool only converts the weights.
I want to use Keras to train my model. So, I define VGG-16 Architecture like this:

```
tmp_model = Sequential()
tmp_model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1),input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))
tmp_model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
tmp_model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
tmp_model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
tmp_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

tmp_model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
tmp_model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
tmp_model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
tmp_model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
tmp_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

tmp_model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
tmp_model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
tmp_model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
tmp_model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
tmp_model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
tmp_model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
tmp_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

tmp_model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
tmp_model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
tmp_model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
tmp_model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
tmp_model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
tmp_model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
tmp_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

tmp_model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
tmp_model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
tmp_model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
tmp_model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
tmp_model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
tmp_model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
tmp_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

tmp_model.add(Flatten())
tmp_model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
tmp_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
tmp_model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
tmp_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
tmp_model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
tmp_model.load_weights('/home/gender.h5')
```

This code loads the weights successfully. Now I want to use the weights of this model to fine tune another network for some other classification task, with a different number of classes. 
Since number of classes is different than in tmp_model, I copy the weights from the tmp_model to my new model's layers, except the last layer, i.e. softmax. The code for the new model, is exactly the same as tmp_model, except for the last layer.
Now what I did, was copy the weights from tmp_model to new model, layer by layer:

```
for i, weights in enumerate(weights_list[0:31]):
    model.layers[i].set_weights(weights)
```

And the problem occurs here. When I run my code, It gives me this error:

```
ValueError: You called `set_weights(weights)` on layer "zero_padding2d_14" with a  weight list of length 3, but the layer was expecting 0 weights. Provided weights: [[[[ 0.27716994  0.05686508  0.0098957  ... -0.055...
```

As I said, tmp_model and model, have the exact same architecture, except for the last layer. Which is why I'm just copying the weight for all the layers, except the last one. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, weights_list only includes layers which contains weights, and normally it only has 16 layers because VGG16 has 16 layers which contain weights . But model.layers ranges from 0 to N, here N is larger than 16 since model.layers includes layers which contains no weights, such as relu layer,padding_layer, and max_pooling layer, so on.